# How to copy rows from one table to another in excel based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm needing code to copy a row of a table in `workbook1` to `workbook2` based on cell value in column `E` of `Workbook1`. If it matches then the row needs to be copied and the cell it matches needs to be changed so it is not copied again

**Pseudo code:**

```
if workbook1 sheet dispatch range E:E= 13 then copy to workbook WIP sheet1. 
AND change cell in workbook1 sheet dispatch range E:E to "131".
```

I have a button on the Dispatch sheet to run the code, Not to have it run automatically.

The current code I found on here deletes the row, but I need it to stay  because it has times formulated on another sheet and it is all printed at the end of the day.

**Current code:**

```
Sub MoveWaitParts()
'move rows from sheet 1 to sheet 2 if column E has a 13 in it.
'for Move Row into new sheet based on cell valueDim Check As Range

lastrow = Worksheets("Dispatch").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastrow2 = Worksheets("wait parts").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult

Response = MsgBox("Are you sure", vbYesNo Or vbDefaultButton2)
If Response = vbYes Then
If lastrow2 = 1 Then
    lastrow2 = 0
    Else
End If
Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E:E"), "13") > 0
    Set Check = Range("E1:E4" & lastrow)
    For Each cell In Check
        If cell = "13" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("wait parts").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
            lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            Else:
        End If
    Next
Loop
End If

End Sub
```

I'm not good enough with coding to piece something together to fit my needs, can someone help?

Comment: So to clarify, you don't want to delete the row on the Dispatch Sheet AND you want to change the value of the cell that equals "13" to "131"? Is the 1 added on the end a code or is one hundred thirty one a significant number?

Comment: It is simply to make the code not loop and keep copying the rows. it could almost be any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some unclear elements to your question, but this should do what I believe you are trying to do. Your original code had some redundant loops that I find easier to just do a single For loop using the LastRow you had calculated earlier. You can, however, convert that loop to a "For Each Cell in Range" fairly easily.

```
Sub MoveWaitParts()


'Set variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim DispatchSht As Worksheet
Dim WaitSht As Worksheet
Set DispatchSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dispatch")
Set WaitSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wait parts")

'Find the last rows in each sheet
lastrow = DispatchSht.Cells(DispatchSht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = WaitSht.Cells(WaitSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Confirm with user
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
Response = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo Or vbDefaultButton2)

If Response = vbYes Then
    'Not sure what this is for, but put in by OP
    'This will overwrite the first line if there is only one line on the Wait Parts sheet
    If lastrow2 = 1 Then
        lastrow2 = 0
    End If

    'Loop through each row and see if the cell in column E = 13
    'If it does, copy the entire row and paste it below the next row on the Wait Parts sheet
    For i = 1 To lastrow
    If DispatchSht.Cells(i, "E").Value = "13" Then
        DispatchSht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=WaitSht.Rows(lastrow2 + 1)
        lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1

        '************Unclear question elements*********
        '//IF THE ADDED 1 IS SOME SORT OF CODE
        'DispatchSht.Cells(i, "E").Value = DispatchSht.Cells(i, "E").Value & "1"
        '//IF THE ADDED 1 IS AN ARITHMETIC FUNCTION OF SOME SORT
        'DispatchSht.Cells(i, "E").Value = DispatchSht.Cells(i, "E").Value * 10 + 1
        '**********************************************

    End If
    Next i 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The only issue I am finding with this, is when I run the macro it pops up an error that a sheet is already using "sheetname" and I have to enter through it until the code is done... Do you have any I have adjusted the code to fit my needs: